# Laravel APIs changing the link of the api

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have been tasked to create APIs but the thing is they need the link to look something like:

www.domain.com/api/example=1?ex2=2

i know how to remove the api prefix but how to make the link if they need to search for something

it's similar to google link when you search if you notice.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your current settings? I don't see any attempt to actually solve the problem here.

Comment: I'm new to laravel, and why do you need my settings ? since i need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass parameters not defined in the route.

```php
// We define a route with the param 'param1'
Route::get('something/{param1}/asdf', 'Controller@action')->name('something');
```

```
// This is what happens when we pass the defined parameter
route('something', ['param1' => 1])                              // yields: 'something/1/asdf
route('something', ['param1' => 'a_string'])                     // yields: 'something/a_string/asdf
// This is what happens when we pass other parameters we didn't define
route('something', ['param1' => 1, 'param2' => 2])               // yields: 'something/1/asdf?param2=2
route('something', ['param1' => 'a_string', 'param2' => 'qwer']) // yields: 'something/a_string/asdf?param2=qwer
```

So for your example:

```
Route::get('api')->name('api.example');
# and then
route('api.example', ['example' => 1, 'ex2' => 2]); // yields '/api?example=1&ex2=2'
```

Comment: so if i give for example route('api.example', ['example => {param}]) should solve my problem ?

Comment: Yes. Just declare the route (don't forget to give it a name) and you're good to go. `route($route_name, $param_array)` You can try it with `php artisan tinker` as well.